# tensorflow.nn.softmax() is producing wrong values from inside the model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, softmax

Why tf.nn.softmax() is giving wrong values from inside the model? But when I am doing softmax manually from outside the model on the returned logits, it is operating as it should.

```
beta = np.random.random((4,1))
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(4,), dtype="float32")
beta = tf.constant(beta, dtype="float32")
utility = tf.matmul(inputs, beta)
logits = tf.reshape(utility,[-1])
probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[logits, probabilities], name="Test")

valX = np.ones((50,4))
logits, probabilities = model.predict(valX)

tf.nn.softmax(logits).numpy()
array([0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02,
       0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02,
       0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02,
       0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02,
       0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02], dtype=float32)

probabilities
array([0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   ,
       0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   ,
       0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   ,
       0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   ,
       0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   ,
       0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.03125   ,
       0.03125   , 0.03125   , 0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556,
       0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556,
       0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556,
       0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556, 0.05555556],
      dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logits, probabilities = model.predict(valX, batch_size=50), would solve the problem.
inputs.shape[0] == 50 in this case and softmax is getting calculated on original axis = 0, across the number of input samples.